# product spaces of rationals 

Tags: gn.general-topology, reference-request

Let $Q$ follow subspace topology from $R$
Then I think it is true that $Q^n$ and $Q^m$ (with product topology) are not homeomorphic.I also think it will be possible to define "rational" homotopy groups by considering $[0,1]\cap Q$ etc. But I can't find any reference regarding topology of product spaces of rationals in general . So I was wondering if someone can give a sketch of a proof and give some references.

Comment: They're homeomorphic.

Comment: can you explain how?

Comment: They're all countable metric spaces with no isolated points. 
See http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/25.htm

Comment: The result mentioned by Apollo above also shows that for *any* nonempty countable metric $X$, $X \times \mathbb Q$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb Q$ - This is one of the results I try to keep in mind to remind myself that my intuition regarding topological spaces is not to be trusted! 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit:** The following is a second attempt to repair problems in earlier proposed solutions, as pointed out by Gerald Edgar in comments. Hopefully this time I've gotten it right this time.

It's classical (by a back-and-forth argument; see for instance A Shorter Model Theory by Hodges) that any two countable dense unbounded linear orders without endpoints are isomorphic. For example the linear order $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $L = \mathbb{Z}_{(2), (5)} \cap (0, 1)$, referring here to the integers localized at the primes 2 and 5 (i.e., rationals whose decimal expansions don't have an infinite tail of 9's or 0's -- this is for technical reasons). $L$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are homeomorphic under their order topologies.

Let $f: L \times L \to \mathbb{Q} \cap (0, 1)$ be the map that takes a pair of elements $\alpha, \beta \in L$ and forms a rational number by interleaving their decimal expansions, with the decimal expansion of $\alpha$ appearing in odd places and that of $\beta$ in the even places. Let $I$ be the image of $f$. The map $f: L \times L \to I$ is a homeomorphism, and $I$ is again a countable dense linear order without endpoints, hence homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$ again. Then the evident composite

$$\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \cong L \times L \stackrel{f}{\to} I \cong \mathbb{Q}$$

is a homeomorphism $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \cong \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Am I confused?  $f : \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ sending $(r,s)$ to $r+s\sqrt{2}$ is a homeomorphism?  Surely you can have $r_n \to \infty$ and $s_n \to -\infty$ in such a way that $r_n+s_n\sqrt{2} \to 0$?

Comment: Sorry!  You are right. I will edit and try to fix this thing. 

Comment: I have substantially edited my answer. Apologies again. If there is still an error, then please (nemesiso) unaccept this answer and I will delete it. I really just wanted something semi-constructive. 

Comment: Isn't the product topology on QxQ the same as the order topology on QxQ determined by the lexicographic order? This, together with back-and-forth, would do the trick.

Comment: @SJR: Sets of the form $\{a\}\times(b,c)$ are open in the lexicographic order topology, but not in the product topology.

Comment: @ Emil: Whoops!     

Comment: "Forbidding tails of zeros" ... a slight problem.  No pair of numbers interleaves to u = 0.40404040404040... despite its being eventually periodic and not having a tail of zeros.

Comment: Bah. Yes. I can't delete my answer though unless nemisiso unaccepts it. Thanks for pointing out the problem, Gerald. Maybe there's some simpleminded fix, but I'm otherwise occupied now. 

Comment: Maybe you can interleave using decimals for something like $\{x+\sqrt{2} : x \in \mathbb Q\}$.

Comment: Thanks Gerald. I think it's fixed now, but what I wrote is inelegant. If I had to do it again, I'd instead use the countable dense linear order $Q$ of quadratic surds between 0 and 1, whose continued fractions are eventually periodic, and interleave those. That seems to me to be a more elegant, less hack-y solution. 

Comment: Your suggestion also seems reasonable. :-)

Comment: OK, I am happy with this version.